# PHP/MySQL Login Not Working

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Can anyone tell me why this simple PHP/MySQL login code is always showing "Wrong username or password" even if I type in the correct username/pass combo? I have spent a ton of time trying to figure this out.

```
<?php
// Database Connection
mysql_connect("IP", "charlesfries", "Password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("charlesfriessdatabase") or die(mysql_error());

// Variables
$username = $_POST["username"]; 
$password = $_POST["password"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'");

// Success
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 1) // Checks for Single Record of Given Username & Password
{
    session_register("username"); // Registers Username Key in Session
    session_register("password"); // Registers Password Key in Session
    header("location:http://charliefries.tk/");
}

// Failure
else
{
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Also, please don't tell me my code is injectable. I know it is.

Here is my form code:

```
<form action="signinprocess.php" method="post"> <!-- Sign In Process -->
Username: <input type="text" name="username" style="width:150">
<br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" style="width:153">
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

Comment: did you try it in phpmyadmin etc?

Comment: I did. The password and username is in the table but this code doesn't retrieve it.

Comment: Are you sure the values are in the `$_POST` array?

Comment: ^ that would probably be the reason

Comment: try echoing out the $_POST['username'] and password and see if it's there.

Comment: might also help if you posted your form code.

Comment: I added the form code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try LIMIT 1 in SELECT to ensure you only have 1 row.

Comment: Turns out I had duplicate entries.

Comment: if ($count == 1) // Checks for Single Record of Given Username & Password.
your database data may contain a duplicated username or password that returns a greater than 1 result.
try to filter and make username unique so that no duplication of accounts and encrypt your password. :)

Comment: @user2113739 : No problem! Glad to be of help. :)

Comment: that's an answer no one expect, since everyone assumed there would be no duplicate accounts

Comment: @user2113739 fix your database accounts this will cause more problems in the future if the user can enter the same username and password. 

Duplication is Evil

Comment: He said the code is always showing "Wrong username or password". The condition for it to be executed is anything other than $count == 1. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few "bad ideas" in your code:

1. Don't use mysql_* for new projects. This is outdated. Switch to mysqli_* http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
2. Selecting by username and password is not always a good idea. In most cases, it is better to search for the username and check, if the password is correct. With prepared statements, you will get something like this

   SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `username`=?

   In the next step, you can check, if your password is the same as in the database, e. g. with a if statement $_POST['password']==$dataFromDB['password'].
3. Currently you are saving the password in plain text. This is a really bad idea. Take a look at bcrypt. See [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)
4. session_register is outdated. Use something like

   $_SESSION['username']=$dataFromDB['username']

As I see, the problem is in the (not existing) LIMIT. Hope these hints will help you anyway.